# Docker-RabbitMQ-NestJS microservices error 406 PRECONDITION_FAILED

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, microservices, nestjs

I'm new to Docker and RabbitMQ and I've been trying for 2 days to solve an error in my docker containers which contains: **api_client, api_consumer, RabbitMQ.** I've done a research and tried to read as many threads with this problem as I found but unfortunately nothing helped.

So here is my code:
**compose.yml**

```
  services:
    api_client:
     build:
      context: ""
      dockerfile: apps/api_client/Dockerfile
     env_file:
      - ./config/.env.local
     restart: always
     ports:
       - "3000:3000"
     depends_on:
       - rabbitmq

    api_consumer:
     build:
      context: ""
      dockerfile: apps/api_consumer/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./config/.env.local
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.9.2-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    hostname: rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/rabbitmq
      - ./rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
```

**main.ts (in api_consumer)**

```
async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
        ApiConsumerModule,
        {
            transport: Transport.RMQ,
            options: {
                queue: 'test_queue',
                urls: ['amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672'],
                queueOptions: {
                    durable: true
                }
            }
        },
    );
    const AWSAppConfig = app.get(AwsAppconfigLoaderService);
    const Log = new Logger(ApiClientService.name);

    await AWSAppConfig.loadAWSAppConfig()
        .then((_) => {
            Log.log(AWSAppConfig.getAppName());
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            Log.error(
                `Error occured while downloading AWS Config: ${JSON.stringify(
                    err,
                )}`,
            );
        });

    await app.listen();
}
bootstrap();
```

**api-client.module.ts (in api_client)**

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            isGlobal: true,
            load: [AppConfig],
        }),
        ClientsModule.register([{
            name: GET_MATCHED_DEVICES,
            transport: Transport.RMQ,
            options: {
                queue: 'test_queue',
                urls: ['amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672'],
                queueOptions: {
                    durable: true
                }
            }
        },
        ]),
        AwsAppconfigLoaderModule,
    ],
    controllers: [ApiClientController],
    providers: [ApiClientService],
})
export class ApiClientModule {}
```

Functionality is simple- when GET on localhost:3000 (**api_client**) is called, it calls (in controller)
 `return this.client.send('getSample', "hello")` 
 
 and then in **api_consumer** it should call (in controller)

```
@MessagePattern('getSample')
    getSample(data): string {
        Logger.debug(data)
        return "It works!";
    }
```

When all docker services start there is the first error:

```
Disconnected from RMQ. Trying to reconnect.
{
 "err": {
  "code": 406,
  "classId": 60,
  "methodId": 40
 }
}
```

And then when I try to access the localhost:3000, this error always occur:

```
Error: Channel closed by server: 406 (PRECONDITION-FAILED) with message "PRECONDITION_FAILED - fast reply consumer does not exist"
```

Both errors come from api_client. 
 
**What I've tried and didn't help:** 
-change durable to false or remove durable options completely 
-add noAck 
-remove queue in adminer on localhost:15672 (which works fine) 
-remove port from urls in both microservices 
-as you can see the queue options are the same in both microservices

 
Now the most absurd thing is that this code **did work absolutely fine** until I started to work on second compose file (and dockerfiles) for local (faster) development with volumes. Then suddenly these errors have started to occur and even if **I undid all my code changes** the errors are still there. Because of this I've wiped all my volumes (with *docker system prune -a --volumes*) many times but still nothing. My OS is Ubuntu 20.04 
I am completely out of ideas so I've written it here in hope for some help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after 5 days of figuring out what causes the error I've found out the problem lies in Nest itself. The bug has been documented [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/7972). I've deleted all the code associated with @nestjs/microservices and tried to use [this approach](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-javascript.html) using amqlib only and the request/response functionality finally works.

Answer (score 0):

The failure occurs because the app can not connect to rabbitmq, the problem resides in your docker compose. Make sure the services are using the same network in docker and are able to communicate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've edited docker compose file with an additional "networks" key (rabbitmq_nestjs: driver: bridge) to connect all three services but the error still occurs. However I've found out that all services should be in the same network by default. Another thing I've tried was adding a new user "admin" because default user "guest" has permissions only for localhost but still without any effect to the error.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds strange but I have had the same problem yesterday, also using a docker-compose file and without making any changes to it  or to the rabbitmq logic, it broke. I tried many things, and when i changed

- `return this.client.send('getSample', "hello")` and `@MessagePattern`
  to
- `return this.client.emit('getSample', "hello")` and `@EventPattern`

thinking it wouldn't make sense for it to fix the issue, it actually did.
I suggest you try that and tell me if it works, sorry if i can't help you more.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, this solution works for me! However I need my microservices to communicate through request-response (message) pattern and not event pattern. I'm trying to figure out why EventPattern works and MessagePattern does not but no success :-(